# Specific de-trending method for damped oscillation?

Tags: filtering, time-frequency, oscillator

Say I have a set signals consisting of damped harmonic oscillations, that I want to extract the characteristics of with the prony method. In the datasets I'm working with, it is possible for these signals to be offset from zero, but otherwise have the characteristics expected.

Detrending with a constant, as in scipy.signal's detrend method, is the simplest way of modifying the data to use the prony method, simply subtracting the mean of the data. However, I am worried this may not result in a signal that is properly "centered", with high peaks potentially resulting in some remaining bias, or worse, creating bias in signals where non existed before.

Has there been any work done into a more reliable way of automatically centering the data when the form of the signal is known?

Comment: Totally off the topic of your question -- I've used Prony's before, and my general feeling is that if you're stuck in an alleyway and you're holding a gun that says "ARMA", and the gun is jammed and the system ID monsters are attacking **now**, use Prony's.  Otherwise, try ARMA first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Prony's method you're taking a signal and extracting a system characteristic polynomial from it.  In $z$-domain terms, you have a known signal $x(n)$ with a $z$ transform
$$X(z) = \frac{N(z)}{P(z)} \tag 1$$
where $P(z)$ is presumed to be the product of a number of resonant second-order pole pairs
$$P(z) = \prod_m z - e^{-\alpha_m \pm j\theta_m} \tag 2$$
If you start from this assumption, then Prony's method will extract the $\alpha_m$ and $\theta_m$ for you.

If you have an $x(n)$ that is polluted by a constant bias, then you can take it to be equal to a zero-mean signal that has been run through an integrator; let
$$x'(n) = h_i(x(n)) \tag3$$
where $H_i(z) = \frac{1}{z - 1}$.

There's two approaches you can take with this:

**Differentiation**

Find $x'(n)$ by numerical differentiation, and do Prony's method on that:
$$x'(n) = x(n) - x(n-1) \tag 4$$

Note that doing this will tend to depress the amplitude of the lower-frequency components; this will be a problem, especially if you're trying to use more than the minimum number of samples to find your roots, which means that you'll be doing a least-squares fit of an overdetermined system of linear equation somewhere in the middle of your solution.

**Assume a pole at $z = 1$**

In the Prony's method discussions that I have seen, you find $P_1 \cdots P_n$, where $n$ is divisible by two, then you factor the polynomial.

Alternately, you can find $P_1 \cdots P_{n+1}$, to get an odd-order polynomial in $z$.  Then you can either divide that polynomial by $z - 1$ or factor it and check that the $1^{st}$ order pole is close to $z = 1$.

In theory you'd get the same results from all three methods.  I'm not sure which one would be less sensitive to numerical issues.

Comment: That's a pretty clever way of approaching it, I'll try this

Comment: I added one and a half suggested methods, in case the first approach doesn't pan out.

Comment: The signals I'm working with so far have been clean enough that numerical issues have not arisen from differentiation, but I will keep the other methods in mind if it comes up in the future, thank you.